# Why can't my picture get uploaded and when it's retrieve the picture is blank

Tags: php, html, mysql

The error that i get when i try to upload it is this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(MTUtODAwLmpwZw==): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\miniproject\imageupload\image.php on line 24

Also i already have a picture inserted in my database and when it is retrieve it just show a plank picture.

This is my code

```
<?PHP
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <br/>
           <input type="file" name="image"/>
            <br/><br/>
           <input type="submit" name="sumit" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
        {
            if (getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE)
            {
                echo "Please select an image.";
            }
            else
            {
                $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $image= file_get_contents($image);
                $image= base64_encode($image);
                saveimage($name, $image);
            }
        }
        displayimage();
        function saveimage($name,$image)
        {
            $con=  mysql_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("kstark",$con);
            $qry="insert into images (name, image) values ('$name','$image')";
            $result=  mysql_query($qry,$con);
            if ($result)
            {
                echo "<br/>Image uploaded.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br/>Image not uploaded.";
            }
        }
        function displayimage()
        {
            $con=  mysql_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("kstark",$con);
            $qry="select * from images";
            $result=  mysql_query($qry,$con);     
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].'">';
            }
            mysql_close($con);
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: **Stop**  using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: Displaying: The image data is not base64, use: `base64_encode()`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - He does actually base64 encode the image before he saves it in the DB.

Comment: Just take a look at any modern tutorial on storing and retrieving images in PHP and MySQL. A modern tutorial will have no mention of the string 'mysql_'

Comment: One also has to question the sanity of storing the image data in the db in the first place and not just a reference to it's location on disk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `tmp_name` rather than the filename when you attempt to retrieve the contents.

```
if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
{
    if (getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE) {
        echo "Please select an image.";
    } else {
        /* use the tmp_name rather than name here! */
        $image=file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] );
        $image=base64_encode($image);
        $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        saveimage($name,$image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, It did solve the error but it still not uploading the pictures.

Comment: When I tried this I get the base64 representation of the image uploaded which is what you want to store in the db. To save the actual image you need to `move_uploaded_file( $name, $path )`